# Handle multiple apply Kubernetes deployment with Terraform & GitlabCI

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, gitlab-ci, amazon-eks

I deploy a Kubernetes environment with two differents `terraform apply`. The first on to deploy the EKS cluster itself and the second one to deploy the differents services.

As suggested here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs#stacking-with-managed-kubernetes-cluster-resources

```
The most reliable way to configure the Kubernetes provider is to ensure that the cluster
itself and the Kubernetes provider resources can be managed with separate apply
operations. Data-sources can be used to convey values between the two stages as needed.
```

I started to build a GitlabCI pipeline and wanted to only try the `terraform plan` command for the commits on a Merge Request.

Given the fact that the second `terraform plan` won't be effective if the first module has not been applied (EKS cluster not created), is there a way to perform the Continuous Integration of the second module without having to deploy the cluster ?

Answer (score 0):

If your "services" module depends on values from your "cluster" module (which it certainly does, as it needs to know where to deploy the resources to), then no, you cannot run a `terraform plan` since it will fail when it tries to load the data sources.

You could possibly use conditionals to eliminate dependencies on the "services" module if a certain variable is given:

```
data "cluster" "my_cluster" {
  count = var.my_flag ? 0 : 1
  id = "myclusterid"
}

resource "my_resource_type" "my_resource" {
  cluster_id = var.my_flag ? null : data.cluster.my_cluster[0]
}
```

And that will prevent it from trying to read data sources that don't exist, but the `terraform plan` will almost certainly always fail since required fields won't accept `null` as a value.